# Separate FloatingActionButton Logic in another class

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, floating-action-button

I want to split my floatingactionbutton logic (Code part) in another class.
Which is the proper way to do it?
Will I get some performance issues separating it?
I am using Butterknife. How to do it with Butterknife?

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private boolean fabClicked = false;
        @BindView(R.id.fab_one) FloatingActionButton fabOne;
        @BindView(R.id.fab_two) FloatingActionButton fabTwo;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);
        }

        @Optional
        @OnClick({R.id.fab_one, R.id.fab_two})
        public void doSomething(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.fab_one:
                    //
                    break;
                case R.id.fab_two:
                    //
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public boolean getFabMenuClicked() {
            return fabMenuClicked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your code is short, you need to add the code in the method within the same class. If your code is a long one, you need to separate it to another class using static method. I suggest to read [Building Maintainable Software, Java Edition](https://www.amazon.com/Building-Maintainable-Software-Java-Future-Proof/dp/1491953527)

Answer (score 0):

It's specific to your case, In Android there is no such best practice defined. I usually keep listener out of main class to avoid thousand lines code into a class.

Please find this example, where I have kept code in separate files, it may help you to separate your listener code into different class.

```
public class SeprateClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context context;
    public SeprateClickListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnOne:
                  break;
            case R.id.btnTwo:
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Assign listener to the view.

```
btnOne.setOnClickListener(new SeprateClickListener(this)); 
btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new SeprateClickListener(this));
```

Comment: as you can see I have butterknife in my code. how to solve this with butterknife?

Comment: this is not the answer. I am using butterknife in my code.

Comment: fabTwo.setOnClickListener(new SeprateClickListener(this)); you can add this kind of code. ButterKnife inject view it's nothing relate with your core logic.

Comment: I have an  onclick with 2 parameters? Tell me how to let it work

Comment: Read this java documentation for pass  value.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: you dont get it? -.-